# Multiple columns cardview to fill landsacpe screen size

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have this challenge: in my portrait mode I used a cardview to contain image and texts in an array, and they took two columns which is fine by me. But, the same arrangement happens in a landscaped android phone, this creates space between and after the image. How do I make the columns in landscape three(3)?
Here is the code for portrait layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_column="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tv_species"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_species"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/custom_two"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So are you working with a `GridView/RecyclerView` and setting the **columns** to 2?

Comment: yea. from the code. I have a cadview inside a linear layout. and within the cardview I have imageview and textview which I used an array to generate. so, my challenge is this: when I run the app on my phone in landscape mode, I still have the image and text occupy two columns as when I run it in portrait mode. So therefore, I have more space in landscape mode and I want to make use of the space by atleast allowing the image and text underneath the image to go across three columns.

Comment: So you are adding these elements in code. Can you please show me the code so i can get a better understanding

Comment: it's shown already. check it out in my first post.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two solutions for your problems:

1. Is to use a `TableLayout` and its `TableRow`.
2. Is to use a `RecyclerView` and a `GridLayoutManager` which is the optimal way in my opinion.

And in both you'll have to detect the **orientation change** in order to change your view columns.

### 1.The TableLayout way

Well you'll add a `TableLayout` as your top view and then add your elements in `TableRow` to make them in the same row ;for example,

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  //One row with two columns
<TableRow
    android:gravity="center">
  //Each view is a column
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView .../>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView .../>
</TableRow>

//One row with three columns
<TableRow
    android:gravity="center">
  //Each view is a column
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView .../>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView .../>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView .../>
</TableRow>
```

This will give you a `TableLayout` with **two** `CardViews` in a **row**, and if you want more columns to be added in the same row you just have to add them to the same `TableRow` tag.

So in your code you can add your standard 2 items per row then when you detect the orientation change you increase the number of columns to 3 like this:

```
    int numberOfColumns = 2;
    //Check your orientation either in your OnCreate or after it 
    if(this.context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
      this.context.getResources().getConfiguration()
      .ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    numberOfColumns = 3;
    //Lets say that items is an array of your items which is 
    the Image and text
    int itemsAdded = 0;
    TableRow tableRow = null;
    for (ItemView itemView : items) {
      //if the number of items added is multiple of number of columns
      //it will add a new row view to the table row
      if(itemsAdded % numberOfColumns == 0){
         tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext)
           //Add your tableRow settings here
           //Layout params
         tableView.addView(tableRow);
       }
       tableRow.addView(itemView);
       itemsAdded++;
    }
```

You can check another example for the `TableLayout` [here](http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98)

---

### 2.The RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager **[Recommended]**

You'll have to do the following:

1. Add this dependency in your **build.gradle** file 
   `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'`
2. Add a `RecyclerView` in your *layout* like this 
   `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/myGridRecyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`
3. Make an `RecyclerViewAdapter` and create and bind your views
4. The you can do this to change the number of columns:

   ```
   int numberOfColumns = 2;
   //Check your orientation in your OnCreate  
   if(this.context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                       this.context.getResources().getConfiguration()
                       .ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
   numberOfColumns = 3;
   this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager
           (this.context,
           numberOfColumns,
           GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
   ```

You can follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) tutorial if you choose to follow this path. Using a `RecyclerView` will benefit you in the future if you wan to add more views to your layout, its easy and dynamic.

---

In both cases you'll need to check your orientation and you can detect it in your `onCreate()` method.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Jhosuer what happened with you??

Comment: Thanks! @M090009 I tried it out but it didn't work out, so, I was trying to implement weightsum and layout_weight but it didn't work out. I still haven't solved it.

Comment: Sorry @Jhosuer for the delayed answer, but i was busy. please checkout the answer its completely different now

Comment: Hey @Jhosuer what did you end up doing?

Comment: I actually changed the parameter from java. This line of my code...                                              if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // The number of Columns . *Change was here*
            mmLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
            mmRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mmLayoutManager);
        }